# How to Show room name With roomid In ListView

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-fragments, adapter

I have try to show roomid in my android app but they are not shows because i am beginner.  please write the code. i have show you my code below,

**RoomListActivity.java Short Code**

```css
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray rooms = jsonObject.getJSONArray("rooms");
for (int i = 0; i < rooms.length(); i++) {
JSONObject room = rooms.getJSONObject(i);
String name = room.optString("room");
String roomid = room.optString("roomid"); 
System.out.println("OutPut Name:"+ name.toString());
System.out.println("OutPut roomid:"+ roomid.toString());
items.add(name);  
}      
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ChatlistView);
ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RoomListActivity.this,  
R.layout.room_row,
R.id.room,
items);
listView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
int position, long id) {
TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.room);
String message = "You clicked # " + position + ", which is string: " + textView.getText().toString();
Toast.makeText(RoomListActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
});
```

**room_row.xml**

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativelay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/room"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img_room"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_room"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/img_room"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="Room Name"
        android:textSize="16dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_room"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/chat" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/roomid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/room"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_room"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/img_room"
        android:layout_below="@+id/room"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="Room Id" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**RoomModel.java**

```css
public class RoomModel {
 private String name, id, roomid;
 public String getName() {
     return name;}
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;}
public String getId() {
return id;}
public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;}
public String getroomId() {
return roomid;}
public void setroomId(String roomid) {
this.roomid = roomid;}
}
```

**OutPut Name: OutPut Room:Logs**

```css
03-10 13:35:33.315: I/System.out(726): OutPut Name:.~=cAsiNo-RooM=~.
03-10 13:35:33.325: I/System.out(726): OutPut roomid:room12
03-10 13:35:33.325: I/System.out(726): OutPut Name:.~=MusiC-Masti=~.
03-10 13:35:33.335: I/System.out(726): OutPut roomid:room24
```

[SnapShot Of App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oHrF.png)

Comment: Please Told Me How I Show the roomid In My App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this Adapter :

```
public class RoomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RoomModel>  {

  private final String TAG = RoomAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
  private final Activity context;
  private List<RoomModel> values;

  public RoomAdapter(Activity context, List<RoomModel> values) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.room_row.xml, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
  }

  public int getCount() {
    return values.size();
  }

  public String getItem(int position) {
    return values.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    if (convertView != null) {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    } else {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.room_row.xml, parent,  false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

         viewHolder.name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.room);
         viewHolder.image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img_room);

    }

    viewHolder.name.setText(getItem(position).getName());

  // dependencies { compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0' }
 Glide.with(context)
            .load( "URL_PICTURE"))
            .placeholder(R.drawable.chat)
            .error(R.drawable.chat)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(viewHolder.image);


    return convertView;
}

 static class ViewHolder {
   TextView name ;
    ImageView image;

 }
}
```

change :

```
   ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
```

To :

```
  ArrayList<RoomModel> items = new ArrayList<>();
```

and

```
  items.add(name);
```

To :

```
 items.add(new RoomModel(roomid, name));
```

and try this :

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ChatlistView);
RoomAdapter mArrayAdapter = new RoomAdapter(context,items)
listView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
```

add this constructor in your class RoomModel :

```
public RoomModel(String roomid, String name) 
{ 
   this.roomid = roomid; 
   this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: you mean roomid items.add(roomid); ? how to include the activity "RoomAdapter,java" in RoomListActivity

Comment: items.add(new RoomModel(roomid, name)); the code is giving me error "Description Resource Path Location Type
The constructor RoomModel(String, String) is undefined RoomListActivity.java /wap2mob/src/com/android/wap2mo line 113 Java Problem"

Comment: add this constructor in your class RoomModel :
 public RoomModel(String roomid, String name) {
        this. roomid  = roomid;       
        this. name  = name;
    }

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
items.add(name);
```

here you are adding only names into the `arraylist` so you are getting only names in the `listView`. To get roomname,roomId make `arraylist` of Roommodel class

```
ArrayList<Roommodel> items = new ArrayList<Roommodel>();
```

and add those objects to the list

```
items.add(room1);
```

Comment: you mean roomid items.add(roomid); ? how to include the activity "RoomAdapter,java" in RoomListActivity

Comment: RoomAdapter mArrayAdapter = new RoomAdapter(context,items); "Description Resource Path Location Type
context cannot be resolved to a variable RoomListActivity.java /wap2mob/src/com/android/wap2mob line 120 Java Problem
"

Comment: Thanks Man I fix The All Error's. I am facing Error last 2 weak today solve all error.  Thank you Thank you  You Are Great Man.